# Pop-up window appear behind the active window in Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, bug

[image: bug]

I downloaded the iso file from Microsoft and installed Windows 11. After, I've had this happen several times. A confirmation window that appears when I delete files, and a progress window that appears when I move files appear behind the currently open window.

It doesn't always happen, but it seems to happen more often when I'm trying to delete a file I don't have permission for, or when I try to copy a file to another device.

To make matters worse, because Windows 11's taskbar doesn't support ungrouping apps, I always have to find it manually, which is very inconvenient.

I am using version 21H2 22000.613. If anyone has experienced this and found a solution, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried a full repair of Adobe Creative Cloud?  Was this an in-place upgrade from Windows 10?   Otherwise I am not certain what might cause this.

Comment: I don't think this is an Adobe related issue. The same thing happens when deleting files in C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download after a fresh reboot.

Comment: The image suggested Adobe Creative Cloud sorry if I misinterpreted .  I do not get this popup in Windows 11 deleting files in Software Distribution (providing they are eligible for deletion).

Comment: Why are you deleting files out of C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download?

Comment: @John Even if you reboot and try these things right away? If you've never experienced anything like this before, you're just fine. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @istist   - I would normally (almost all the time) use Disk Cleanup to remove files here. Right now I only see 9MB here so nothing to manually delete.   I suggest you use Disk Cleanup and the "bug" will likely vanish.